# How to get current altitude in ios 8?

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I have trouble to find the altitude of the device, I need in my app to show the altitude How can I do that?
I have tried that:

```
 var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
    var alt = newLocation.altitude
    print("\(alt)")
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
```

nothing show up....

Comment: Have you added the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your `info.plist`?

Comment: Did you include `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your info.plist ?

Comment: Actually the OP is asking for in use authorization, so he'd need an NSLocationInUseDescription, or whatever the in use version is called.

Comment: Yes, I think the func locationManager don't get called and I don't know how to call it. is it the problem? @WMios

Comment: @MalicOfSdom, that's where you're printing so you would need that to get called.

Comment: It is not working.... @WMios

Comment: Do you get promoted to grant location access?  If not then check that NSLocationWhenInUseUsageKey is set in your info.plist. Also, stopping location updates after the first update isn't a good idea. The first location fix likely won't be very accurate. You need a four satellite GPS fix to get altitude, so you should check whether you have a reasonable `verticalAccuracy` before stopping updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you are not calling the right delegate method, you are calling : 
`locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!)`  but the one that will give you what you want is `locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`,

So if you did implement the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key into your `Info.plist` file and if the popup is showing you just have to remove your function and add this one, it should work :

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let lastLocation = locations.last else {
        NSLog("error no last location")
        return
    }
    let altitude = lastLocation.altitude
     // Do what you want with your altitude
}
```

I also suggest you to call `locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()` not inside this delegate function.

Hope this will help you !

**Note :** This syntax is for Swift 3.0, but I think that you just have to remove the `_` in the delegate function for Swift 2.2.

Comment: According to the [AppleDocumentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/altitude), 
`The altitude measured in meters. (read-only)`